# How do I remove this roller blinder for cleaning?

Tags: blinds

In Ireland we have this Luxaflex roller blinder:
[image]
[image]
[image]

It seems that should be possible to remove the blind for cleaning without having to remove the screws from the wall. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to remove it.

On the endcap side (the opposite side to the chain mechanism), push the lever back towards the bracket and slide the blind away from the window.
The lever is spring loaded so you have to keep pressing it.

[image]

In my case the lever was at the top of the endcap.

Answer (score 2):

Often roller shade brackets have protruding metal tabs or ears or clips, that, when pushed or pulled, allow the roller to be withdrawn from the bracket. This appears to be a different mechanism.

Here, the only seemingly-moveable part is the white annular cylinder (the piece with the horizontal slot) shown in the top photo. This piece appears to rotate around the roller's axis. In some position, the slot will be positioned to allow the roller's end tab to be withdrawn through the slot and therefore out of engagement with the bracket, thus freeing that end of the roller. The correct position is likely to be with the slot horizontal or downward, as there's no room for the roller to move either upward or towards the window glass.

Thus, rotate the white annular cylinder until the roller can be pulled free from the bracket.